# Is it possible to have a zero-cost assert() such that code should not have to be modified between debug and release builds?

Tags: c++, testing, assert

I've noticed that some code often looks like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
assert(i == 1);
#endif //DEBUG
```

and that you may have several blocks of these sitting around in your raw code. Having to write out each block is tedious and messy.

Would it be plausible to have a function like this:

```
auto debug_assert = [](auto expr) { 
 #ifdef DEBUG
 assert(expr);
 #endif //DEBUG
};
```

or something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
auto debug_assert = [](bool expr) {
  assert(expr);     
};
#else //DEBUG
void debug_assert(bool expr) {}
#endif //DEBUG
```

to get a zero-cost assert when the DEBUG flag is not specified? (i.e. it should have the same effect as if it was not put into the code without the lambda running, etc. and be optimized out by the g++/clang compilers).

Comment: You can already disable `assert` from `<cassert>` by defining `NDEBUG`...

Comment: *"code often looks like this"* - Often? Really?

Comment: It takes a lot of confidence and courage to ship code with asserts enabled.  And if you ship with disabled-asserts, you need to test with disabled-asserts, as we all ship what we test, right?  These are difficult issue on deliverable software.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I actually hate `assert()`'s. They help little in giving information about the offending code, and seeing these in production code is the worst possible situation.

Comment: Good point, and maybe not so easily solved, but it can be done.   I have adapted a boost desktop assert for use in embedded systems long ago.   Example use:  "dtbAssert(condition)(val1)(val2)(val3)" when assert fails, it prints the value of val1 thru val3.  [Any number of values can be displayed.]    My assert also provides: 1) "disableExitOnAssert()", so user can attach debugger and inspect the call stack. 2)  "resume()" - when in debugger at a dtbAssert, this command cancels the assert and allows the thread to resume.  Several projects back my team had 3000+ asserts .. we liked them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by @KerrekSB, you can already disable asserts by defining `NDEBUG` before including `<cassert>`. The best way to ensure that it's defined before including the header file is to list it in as the argument to the compiler (with gcc it's `-DNDEBUG`)

Note: the `assert` is removed by replacing it with a no-op expression, and there, the argument isn't evaluated *at all* (which is different from your suggested solution)! This is why it's of utmost importance to not call any functions that have side effects in `assert`.

For completeness: here is how `assert` can be implemented:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#ifndef NDEBUG
#define assert(EXPRESSION) ((EXPRESSION) ? (void)0 : (printf("assertion failed at line %d, file %s: %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__, #EXPRESSION), exit(-1)))
#else
#define assert(EXPRESSION) (void)0
#endif
```

Introducing your own `assert`-style macro is very commonly done. There are quite a lot of reasons you may want to do this:

- you want to include more information about the evaluated expression (see Catch's `REQUIRE` and how they use expression templates to decompose the expression into individual elements and stringify them)
- you want to do action other than `exit()`ing the program, like throwing an exception, mailing the developer, logging to a file, breaking into the debugger
- you want to evaluate the expression even on release builds which is less error prone than not evaluating it at all (after all, if it doesn't have side effects, it can be eliminated by a compiler optimizations, and if it does, you just avoided a heisenbug)
- and so on, and so on (if you have an idea, you can post a comment, I'll add it to the answer)